# connection to cassandra instance which is running on localhost

Tags: java, cassandra, nosql

can somebody help and answer me, why I can not connect and get an error in netbeans. I get the following error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/slf4j/LoggerFactory   at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.(Cluster.java:63)    at
>   testcassandra.TestCassandra.main(TestCassandra.java:30) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)     ... 2 more

(with Datstax DevCenter I can connect)

Error at cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("localhost").withPort(9042).build();

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Row;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;

public class TestCassandra {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Cluster cluster;
    Session session;
    // Connect to the cluster and keyspace "demo"
    cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("localhost").withPort(9042).build();
    session = cluster.connect("demo");
    // Insert one record into the users table
    session.execute("INSERT INTO users (lastname, age, city, email, firstname) VALUES ('Jones', 35, 'Austin', 'bob@example.com', 'Bob')");
    // Use select to get the user we just entered
    ResultSet results = session.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE lastname='Jones'");
    for (Row row : results) {
        System.out.format("%s %d\n", row.getString("firstname"), row.getInt("age"));
    }
    cluster.close();
}
```

}

Comment: You seem to be missing the [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org) library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you may be missing the proper package.  You can download the JAR file [here](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html)  That site also has full documentation on how to implement as well.

If you are still having issues after installing verify that you are not using BOTH SLF4J and Log4j 2 as they will cause events to endlessly be routed between them.

Please also make sure you have the correct import statement

Example:

```
 import org.slf4j.Logger;
 import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

OR

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
```